# How is the swoosh done on beautyoftheweb.com?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

On [Beauty of the Web](http://beautyoftheweb.com), there is a purple/blue swoosh at the beginning, if you are in IE9 or Chrome. How is that done? What is that? How come it only displays in IE9 and Chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a video placed with html5. Look for id="streak". Here is the video if you care :)

http://az6680.vo.msecnd.net/botwcontent/assets/videos/layout/streak.mp4

Edit: The html that actually does this

```
<div id="streak">
        <video id="vid" src="http://az6680.vo.msecnd.net/botwcontent/assets/videos/layout/streak.mp4">
        </video>
        <canvas id="streak_canvas" width="1920" height="256"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Comment: And it probably only works in IE9 and Chrome because those browsers support the video tag.

Comment: Those are the only browsers it works in because they support the `<video>` tag *and* H.264. Firefox supports `<video>`, but not H.264.

Comment: @Amir: Firefox also supports the video tag, just not the H.264 codec which the site uses. Pre-4.0, Firefox supports only Theora, which in the end, lost the HTML5 video race.

Comment: @Ashley Williams - Firefox did NOT lose the HTML5 video race and it's still being run. H.264 is patent encumbered and not free in all cases, a standards no-no which will probably kill it. Ogg might have a patent issue but that's not known and is very much a contender. Possibly the final codec will be WebM. Owned by Google and released into the wild, it's supported by all browsers but IE.

Comment: @Rob: Theora has lost, though. It's used by one browser at the moment, which come early next year will also have WebM support.

Comment: @Ashley Williams - Wrong. Firefox, Opera and Chrome all support Theora, along with Konqueror and Epiphany. Theora is still in the running for this; more so than H.264.

Comment: @Rob: I stand corrected. But I still disagree; Theora has less support than H.264, and soon enough, WebM. H.264's essentially supported by *every* browser via a Flash fallback, and since you're already encoding to H.264 for the Flash fallback, you may as well serve it via <video> to Chrome/Safari/iOS/IE9/FF4 too. The only major browsers you're left to deal with then are FF <4 and Opera <10, both of which will suffice with the Flash fallback. Theora is only still in the running if people can be bothered to waste time encoding for a few edge cases, which I doubt they will.

Comment: @Ashley Williams - H.264 will NEVER get into the standard because it's patent encumbered as I said.

Comment: @Rob: I never said it'd get into the standard, just that it'd be more prevalent than Theora. Google, Apple and Microsoft, among others, are all backing H.264, so it isn't going anywhere. Theora on the other hand, hasn't got nearly as much support, so I'd be absolutely gobsmacked if it ever became the de-facto web video standard. Anyhow, we appear to be at an impasse, so let's leave it there. May the best codec win.

Comment: @Ashley Williams - Google does not back H.264 but only allows support in Chrome. Google only promotes WebM. The only potential "winners" in all this will be Theora or WebM for general web content and any consideration in the standard if one is to be selected.

Answer (score 1):

home.video.streak.js is the JS that is controlling the video.

```
var homeVideo;
var homeVideoTimer;
var homeVideoCanvas;
var homeVideoCanvasCtx;
function beginBackgroundVideo() {
    try {
        homeVideo = document.getElementById("vid");
        homeVideoCanvas = document.getElementById('streak_canvas');
        homeVideoCanvasCtx = homeVideoCanvas.getContext('2d');
        homeVideoCanvas.style["display"] = "block";
        homeVideoTimer = setInterval(drawBackgroundVideo, 16);
    } catch (e) { //sometimes, modernizr canvas detection fails
    }
}
function drawBackgroundVideo() {
    if (!isNaN(homeVideo.duration)) {
        if (homeVideo.ended === true) {
            homeVideoCanvas.style["display"] = "none";
            clearInterval(homeVideoTimer);
            return;
        } else {
            homeVideo.play();
        }
        // Draw the video
        try {
            homeVideoCanvasCtx.drawImage(homeVideo, 0, 0, homeVideoCanvas.width, 250);
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }
} /*   paste in your code and press Beautify button   */
if ('this_is' == /an_example/) {
    do_something();
} else {
    var a = b ? (c % d) : e[f];
}
```

and on the page its here:

```
<div id="streak">
        <video id="vid" src="http://az6680.vo.msecnd.net/botwcontent/assets/videos/layout/streak.mp4">
        </video>
        <canvas id="streak_canvas" width="1920" height="256" style="display: inline; "></canvas>
</div>
```

looks like its doing via canvas.

Answer (score 0):

It's an MP4 file http://az6680.vo.msecnd.net/botwcontent/assets/videos/layout/streak.mp4

The reason it only works in Chrome and IE9 is because it's in a `<video>` tag, which is only in HTML5.